# .NET Core 6.0: xUnit Test Fails But Everything is Alright! I Get Unexpected Output (NotFoundResult Instead of NoContentResult)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, xunit

I'm working on a .NET Core 6.0 Web API.
I have a `DeleteComment` method and I have written a test method for it as following:

```
[Fact]
    public void DeleteComment_WithValidId_ReturnsNoContentResult()
    {
        var commentId = 1;

        var result = _controller.DeleteComment(commentId);

        Assert.IsType<NoContentResult>(result);
        _mockCommentService.Verify(service => service.DeleteComment(commentId), Times.Once);
    }
```

// DELETE: api/Comments/5

```
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteComment(int id)
    {
        var deletingComment = _commentService.GetComment(id);
        if (deletingComment == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        _commentService.DeleteComment(id);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

Get Comment By ID:

```
public Comment GetComment(int id)
    {
        return _comments.FirstOrDefault(comment => comment.Id == id);
    }
```

Delete Comment:

```
public void DeleteComment(int id)
    {
        var commentToDelete = _comments.FirstOrDefault(comment => comment.Id == id);
        if (commentToDelete != null)
        {
            _comments.Remove(commentToDelete);
        }
    }
```

While it should return `NoContentResult`, It unexpctedly returns `NotFoundResult`. I tested the API with the same commentId using Postman and Breakpoints and It works properly. Is there any mistake in my code?

Here is the result of running `DeleteComment_WithValidId_ReturnsNoContentResult()` Test

```
Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NoContentResult
Actual:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult
```

Comment: when you use debug  test,in the method "GetComment" ,what it is you see?

Comment: Debug your population of `_comments`. I suspect that however you fill it in your test, it gets not initialized properly. When you run the production code, dependency injection has run, db connections were established, etc. Your unit test appears to not initialize the unit under test properly. Set a breakpoint in the test, I am sure `_comments` will be null. Set it in production and you will see values.

Comment: Everything is definitely not alright.  you need to mock out your calls to the service.  GetComment(...) should return a comment. you will also have to mock out the call to DeleteComment(..) as well.  The Verify call isn't even getting hit because your Assert is short-circuiting the test.